# Cyclone IV FPGA: How to use nCSO pin (101) as normal I/O pin?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

(I'm new to this -- so sorry if this is a dumb question).

I've got a RZ-EasyFPGA dev board with a built in VGA port.
I want mess around with generating a simple VGA signal.

**Dev board pin-out:**
[image: Dev board pinout]

I need to assign PIN 101 as hsync within my Verilog module however, I'm running into compiler issues with the pin already being reserved for `ALTERA_nCEO'.

```
Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_101 (IOPAD_X34_Y18_N21)
Info (176311): Pin hsync is assigned to pin location Pin_101 (IOPAD_X34_Y18_N21)
Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_nCEO~ is assigned to pin location Pin_101 (IOPAD_X34_Y18_N21)
```

I've had a look around for solutions & found pin 101 is a 'dual purpose pin'. I've tried to setting it as regular I/O within 'Device & Pin Options' with no luck.

[image: pin options]

Comment: please proofread your post

Comment: Changing nCEO to regular IO using that dialog should be sufficient. What is your programming scheme set to (e.g. passive serial. etc.)?